# can we create a software application for the full script of selenium coding we have done?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, java, test-automation-framework, testng

If we have created some selenium code for web application testing. After completion of the script coding, can we create a java application or something like that?

Comment: I've implemented it several times. It can be a pain though depending on how you implement your tests.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

You can create an application to run your test scripts, when you create your test projects they are just libraries/dlls that you have created and they do work just like any other library/dll.

add to references and you should be able to call specific tests and get their pass/fail value when they are finished.